# Speed up a while loop in Matlab using cellfun

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I have the following code in Matlab.

```
pc = [0.0195    0.2356    0.6280
    0.0229    0.2356    0.6280
    0.0393    0.2318    0.6180
    0.0196    0.2350    0.6310
    0.0212    0.2343    0.6290
    0.0230    0.2350    0.6310
    0.0245    0.2332    0.6260
    0.0378    0.2313    0.6210
    0.0408    0.2294    0.6160
    0.0426    0.2302    0.6180];

x = pc(:,1);
y = pc(:,2);
z = pc(:,3);

dt = delaunayTriangulation(pc);
dtTri = [dt(:,[1,2,3]);dt(:,[2,3,4]);dt(:,[1,2,4]);dt(:,[1,3,4])];
dtTri = unique(sort(dtTri,2),'rows');

i = 1;
lim = .005;

while (i<=size(dtTri,1))
    d12 = sqrt(abs(x(dtTri(i,1))-x(dtTri(i,2)))^2+...
        abs(y(dtTri(i,1))-y(dtTri(i,2)))^2+...
        abs(z(dtTri(i,1))-z(dtTri(i,2)))^2);

    if (d12>lim)
        dtTri(i,:)=[];
        continue;
    end
    i = i+1;
end
```

Is there any way in Matlab to reduce the running time of the above code (`while` loop), using something like `cellfun`? Because my `pc` size is very large and it takes a long time to run the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, you can remove the whole `while` and replace it with the following code:

```
 d12 = sqrt((x(dtTri(:,1))-x(dtTri(:,2))).^2 + ...
 (y(dtTri(:,1))-y(dtTri(:,2))).^2 + ...
 (z(dtTri(:,1))-z(dtTri(:,2))).^2);
 foundLimit = find(d12 <= lim);
 newDtTri = dtTri(foundLimit,:);
```

Comment: It works fine. Thank you very much. Just changed 'foundLimit = find(d12 < lim);'

Comment: @Huádéní華得尼 my pleasure. ya. you're right. it's updated.